# Algorithm for invalidation / refresh system in Guis

Tags: java, .net, c++

I'm making a Gui for games, and I only want the Gui to redraw a widget when it is necessary. Is there an algorithm to knowing when the widget needs to be invalidated? otherwise it seems very error prone.

Thanks

How does Windows's GUI do it.

Comment: What does .Net and C++ nave to do with a Java GUI, and if it is not a Java based GUI, why did you include the Java tag?

Comment: It's the shot-gun approach to tags.

Comment: As to how Windows' GUI does it, you can study either WPF, or the traditional Windows API (aka `user32.dll`, aka MFC, aka Winforms). MSDN is bound to have lots of documentation on this topic. For the traditional Windows API, search for information on stuff like [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213%28VS.85%29.aspx), `WM_INVALIDATE` (window messages), or [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28VS.85%29.aspx), etc. and advance from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an algorithm to knowing when the widget needs to be invalidated?

Generally when you change a property of your widget.

If you look at the standard Swing components they always repaint when methods like setFont(), setBackground(), setText(), setLocation(), setSize() ... are invoked.

I have no idea what your widget does buy you should follow the same concept, that is is you change a property that affects the painted stated of the widget then revalidate() and repaint() it.

Answer (score 0):

it's not really an algorithm at the level of your question.

In the OO world, you will make an object out of the 'widget'
then that 'widget' will be aware of where it is in the world.

then you can check whether any other widget overlaps with it for redraw - or if it has moved etc.

Comment: Not exactly, when I move my mouse over a button, it highlights, and that is not in any of what you mentioned. What about a font change?